# Does hierarchical agglomerative clustering with centroid-linkage suffer from chain-effect?

Tags: clustering

It is known that the results of hierarchical agglomerative clustering using **single-link method** in order to determine the inter-cluster distance suffer form the **chain-effect** (natural clusters tend to extend trough a line of few points, like in the image below).

Does **centroid-linkage** have the same disadvantage?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The potential worst cases of centroid linkage are probably too crazy to explain as easy as the single-link effect... To see how it reacts to the classic Single-Link problem, why don't you just try yourself?

Roughly, because of the way centroid linkage works, it may end up using a virtual cluster center that is *outside* of the actual cluster. You then may see some very weird links to happen. That is also why it can have non-monotone linkage levels (so later merges may be cheaper than earlier merges).